# Functional component after being called 5 times and wrapping in React.Fragment tag still not displaing anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>

   <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

   <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <Div id="asdfg"></Div>
</body>
<script type="text/babel">


function Dalo()
{    return (
       <h1>bhj</h1>

    )
}

function Panch ()
{
    return 
    (   <React.Fragment>
        <Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render( <Panch/> , document.getElementById("asdfg") );

</script>
</html>
```

Here nothing is being rendered after calling function Panch.

Comment: The parenthesis after return must be on the same line as the return itself

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis after the return must be on the same line as the return itself. So change this:

```
  return 
    (   <React.Fragment>
        <Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

to

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/><Dalo/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
```